# Striping Rows of a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've read posts here on SO about striping a UITableView's cells, but have not been able to work out the details.  My code is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Setup code omitted

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Blah Blah";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Blah blah blah";
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    if ([indexPath row] % 2 == 1) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor     = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.9 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0];
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor       = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.9 blue:0.9 alpha:0.0];
        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.9 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0];
        cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor   = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.9 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

And my result is:

http://img2.pict.com/18/df/b9/2661271/0/screenshot20100127at3.png

Any ideas why this is happening?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

These cells get reused, you should set it back to normal in the case of `[indexpath row] % 2 == 0`

Comment: Did that, but it didn't fix anything.  Still getting the same effect seen above.

Answer (score 2):

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
         [cell setBackgroundColor: indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? color1 : color2];
```

}